# Javascript this vs using same var name within itself

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript, can someone please help me understand if there is a fundamental difference between these 2 ways

First where I use `this` to call a function defined inside the var itself

```
var TxMmm={
  name: {},
  timeout: 2000,
  testFunc1: function(){
    console.log("testFunc1");
    testFunc2();
    this.testFunc3();
  },
  testFunc3: function(){
    console.log("Test func3");
  }
}
function testFunc2(){
  console.log("This is func2 is outside var");
}
```

v/s Below where I use the var `TxMmm` to call function defined inside itself.

```
var TxMmm={
  name: {},
  timeout: 2000,
  testFunc1: function(){
    console.log("testFunc1");
    testFunc2();
    TxMmm.testFunc3();
  },
  testFunc3: function(){
    console.log("Test func3");
  }
}
function testFunc2(){
  console.log("This is func2 is outside var");
}
```

Comment: Try changing `var TxMmm` -> `var TxMmm2` and see how both work afterwards. Next try eliminating the variable entirely.

Comment: There are some good points to be made about this. I wonder if they've already been made in an SO answer somewhere.

Comment: Related, but not (I don't think) targets for closure: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

In that specific code there isn't that much difference, because the object is a singleton. Some differences:

1. In your first code block using `this`, `this` could refer to something other than the `TxMmm` object in (say) `testFunc1`, depending on how `testFunc1` is called. For instance, this would fail:

   ```
   const fn = TxMmm.testFunc1;
   fn();
   ```

   But in your second code block, `TxMmm` will refer to the object (unless the next point comes into play), so that would work. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).
2. If someone does:

   ```
   const x = TxMmm;
   TxMmm = somethingElse;
   x.testFunc1();
   ```

   ...your first code block using `this` will keep working, because `this` is set by how `testFunc1` is called. But your second code block using `TxMmm` would fail, because `TxMmm` doesn't point to the object anymore.
3. It almost never matters (seriously, very nearly never), but in your second code block, when you use `TxMmm`, the JavaScript engine has to look up that identifer to find it in the enclosing scope. Your code using `this` is able to resolve it immediately (since those aren't arrow functions), which in ***very*** rare situations can be faster in a noticeable way.

For non-singleton objects, `this` can be very important, since it tells the code which object's properties to use.